# Swift: UIBeizerPath CAShapelayer filling when fill commented

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, rounded-corners, cashapelayer

I am using UIBeizerPath with roundedRect and a CAShaplayer to attach to my UIView. I have commented out the filling but it is still filling the rectangle.

All I am trying to do is have the rounded rectangular line around the outside.

I am guessing that roundedRect is a solid and I may have to use the UIBeizerPath or fill with clear but I have not been able to find documentation.

This is my code:

```
    let rect: CGRect = frontview.bounds
    var shape: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 5.0)
    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = shape.CGPath
    //shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 1, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1).CGColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
    self.frontview.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `fillColor` to `nil`.

```
shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

*“Default is opaque black.”*

— Documentation of `fillColor` property.

Comment: Missed that one. Thanks!

Comment: @NicholasMuir You are welcome. You are not the first one to hit this issue. I learned from my mistakes :P